# Is it safe to remove elements from a collection.mutable.HashSet during iteration?

Tags: scala

A mutable Set's `retain` method is implemented [as follows](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/SetLike.scala#L136):

```
def retain(p: A => Boolean): Unit =
  for (elem <- this.toList) // SI-7269 toList avoids ConcurrentModificationException
    if (!p(elem)) this -= elem
```

But if I implement my own method that doesn't make a copy for iterating, nothing blows up.

```
def dumbRetain[A](self: mutable.Set[A], p: A => Boolean): Unit = 
  for (elem <- self)
    if (!p(elem)) self -= elem

dumbRetain(mutable.HashSet(1,2,3,4,5,6), Set(2,4,6))
// everything is ok
```

I see that [SI-7269](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7269)'s test case uses the JavaConversions wrapper around a java Set/Map, and it seems like the issue arises from the underlying java collection.

I know there will never be a java collection passed to my algorithm, so can I use `dumbRetain` without worrying about the ConcurrentModificationException? Or is this "coincidental behavior" that I shouldn't rely on?

**edit** to clarify, I would be using `dumbRetain` as an implementation detail in an algorithm which would be in full control of what it passes to `dumbRetain`. And this would be run in a single-threaded context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to rely on the specific implementation of `mutable.HashSet`, and there is nothing in the API that guarantees that it would work for all other implementations of `mutable.Set`, even if we exclude all wrappers for the Java collections.

The `for`-loop

```
for (elem <- self) {
  ...
}
```

is desugared into `foreach`, which for `mutable.HashSet` is implemented as follows:

```
override def foreach[U](f: A => U) {
    var i = 0
    val len = table.length
    while (i < len) {
      val curEntry = table(i)
      if (curEntry ne null) f(entryToElem(curEntry))
      i += 1
    }
}
```

Essentially, it simply loops through the `Array` of the underlying `FlatHashTable`, and invokes the passed function `f` on every element. The whole `foreach` simply does not have any lines which could throw anything, it doesn't check for concurrent **[footnote-1]** modifications at all.

A `ConcurrentModificationException` seems to be the less troubling case: at least, your program fails fast, and even returns a detailed stack trace that points to the line in which the problem occurred. It would be actually *much worse* if it simply deteriorated into undefined behavior without throwing anything. This would be the worst case. However, this worst case shouldn't occur for collections from the standard library: [Throw ConcurrentModificationException exception's in scala collections? #188](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/188)

Quote:

> In scala/scala#5295 (merged in to 2.12.x) I made sure that removing the element last returned from an iterator would not cause a problem for the iterator.

So, as long as you clearly state in the documentation that only the collections from standard library are supported, you will most likely not have any problems using it in your own code. But if you use it in a public interface, this would be an invitation for a bug analogous to "SI-7269" quoted in your question.

**[footnote-1]** "concurrent" as in "ConcurrentModificationException", not as in "concurrently executed threads".

**EDIT:** I've tried to choose less ambiguous formulations. Great Thanks @Dima for the feedback and the numerous suggestions.

Comment: Nothing in `scala.collection.mutable` is thread safe. That's a separate issue (if you want mutability with threads, you have to synchronize). The original issue is that java's `HashSet` throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` just because the original set gets modified by the _same thread_ while being iterated over. Scala's implementation does not have that "feature". It's not "luck".

Comment: @Dima You are reading something into my posting what isn't there. I've never claimed that you need multithreading to trigger `ConcModExc`. That's not the point at all here. It's "pure luck", because `mutable.HashSet` just *happens to be* an implementation of `scala.collection.mutable.Set` that doesn't throw this exception. With less luck, some user of Dylan's library, or one of Dylan's colleagues might sooner or later invoke `dumpRetain` on another implementation of `scala.collection.mutable.Set` which is allergic to concurrent modifications. It all can happen in single-thread context.

Comment: @Dima: Maybe my definition of "pure luck" is a bit different from the common conception. Setting argument type to `mutable.Set` and then saying "I know there will never be a java collection passed to my algorithm" is what I'd call "relying on pure luck" here. If it's known that it will be used with `scala.collection.mutable.HashSet` only, then it should be made clear in the function signature.

Comment: the point is that modifying an iterator in the same thread isn't "concurrent". The exception name is a misnomer, and the exception itself is an artifact of java implementation. So, as long as OP isn't using it concurrently, and isn't sending java sets into it, he's fine.

Comment: Re.: setting the type to `Set` ... Well, there are other implementations of the `Set`, that will not throw.  It's too bad, that some of them will, but, I think, it's quite ok to make it a part of a contract ... Just like "this will crash if the `p` is `null`). Surely, with even less luck, you could run into a `NullPointerException` if the set contains a null, but ...

Comment: @Dima on NPE: yes, that's of course a good point. "Just how defensive do you want your method to be"... But with NPE it's a bit different: *no* sensible implementation can do anything useful with a `null`, therefore throwing an NPE is expected. But for CME, there are many possible implementations that could avoid it, therefore a CME might be a bit more "surprising" in a way.

Comment: What are you talking about? You can certainly do meaningful stuff with nulls ... `if (p == null) return self else ... `

Comment: @Dima on "concurrent": I wouldn't call it a misnomer, because iteration and modification really do happen "simultaneously" in the sense that iterations starts, then modification starts, then modification ends, then iteration ends. So it's "concurrent", even though it's not "parallel".

Comment: That's not "simultaneously". "A happens, then B, then C" is the _definition_ of sequential :) And it can most certainly be handled gracefully. Java's implementation is just too lazy to do it.

Comment: @Dima on "meaningful stuff with null": ok, true again. But now we are discussing the precise meaning of "luck", "surprising" and "meaningful". In *my very personal subjective opinion* it would be more surprising if I got `null` as result of `retain` than if I got an `NPE`. On "simultaneously": I don't know how I could have expressed clearer that the time intervals of iteration and modification intersect (they are nested). "A starts happening, B happens, A finishes happening" is not the archetypical example for "sequential" imho, but I don't own a degree in linguistics, so what do I know? ;)

Comment: The point is, there are kinds of API contracts, not expressible in formal language, that have to be inferred from documentation or common sense.
Like "don't send nulls here" or "this function doesn't handle collections that don't like to be modified while being iterated over".

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can do it, as long as you are sure this is the scala's native `HashSet` implementation, not a wrapper around java ... and with understanding, that this is not thread-safe, and should never be used concurrently (the original `HashSet.retain` is that way too as well as the other mutators).

Better yet, just use immutable `Set.filter`, unless you actually have *real hard evidence* (not just intuition) demonstrating that your specific case absolutely requires mutable container.